# How to get list of nearby Carriers (GSM) with information in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, gsm, carrier

I want to get nearby list of available carriers GSM information in iOS.
dose not matter if it's in ObjC or Swift.

Is there any possibility to get the list?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This information is not available to apps.

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks for quick reply. do we have any apple document that says this is not possible? As I searched a lot but I did not find anything for proof.

Comment: Apple doesn't have a list of things you can't do; it would potentially be infinitely long. It isn't generally possible to prove that something doesn't exist, you can only prove that something does exist. However, if you conduct a thorough search then you can make a case that something doesn't exist. Certainly I have never seen any api that would provide this information and I can see why Apple wouldn't provide such information; it has privacy implications.

Comment: @Paulw11 yes privacy will be there. But still I need to submit some proof that this is not possible right now in iOS. But okay thank you for your quick reply.

Comment: I guess you could start with the [Core Telephony](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretelephony) documentation. Since the capability isn't documented there you can pretty safely assume that it isn't possible.

Comment: yes @Paulw11 I have seen this and also getting connected information but not near by so I only have this proof thank you.